# Apache Camel onExceptionOccurred component not redelivering as per the redelivery delay

Tags: apache-camel

I have Apache Camel route which invokes restlet component and used redelivery mechanism from the exception handler which performs some processing on every failure to update my database record but if I provide the redelivery delay of 2000, it is taking 24 seconds to retry the every preceding attempt. Below is the piece of code. Let me know why it is taking more delay than expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd  http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf    http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">
    <!-- CXF Rest Endpoint Declaration -->
    <cxf:rsServer address="http://localhost:9092/rest/corp"
        id="FetchCDFRestRequest" serviceClass="com.tcl.Service.Service" />

    <bean class="com.tcl.ExceptionOccurredRefProcessor" id="exProc" />

    <bean class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder"
        id="DLCErrorHandler">
        <property name="deadLetterUri"
            value="activemq:queue:DMS.FAILURES.DLQ" />
        <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy"
        id="redeliveryPolicy">
        <property name="maximumRedeliveries"
            value="3" />
        <property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
        <property name="retryAttemptedLogLevel" value="WARN" />
    </bean>
    <camelContext id="Corp"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <errorHandler id="eh" onExceptionOccurredRef="exProc">
            <redeliveryPolicy id="redeliveryPolicy" />
        </errorHandler>

        <route errorHandlerRef="DLCErrorHandler"
            id="MainRouteOppIDFolder" streamCache="true">
            <from id="_CreateOppIDFolder"
                uri="restlet:http://localhost:9092/rest/corp/createOppIDFolder?restletMethod=POST" />
            ----------
            <to uri="restlet:http://localhost:9902/CreateOppIDFolder?restletMethod=POST" />
            ------------    
            <onException id="_onException1"
                onExceptionOccurredRef="exProc"
                redeliveryPolicyRef="redeliveryPolicy" useOriginalMessage="true">
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <simple>true</simple>
                </handled>
                <log id="_log3" loggingLevel="INFO"
                    message="Handled ex >>>>> ${exception.message} " />
            </onException>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

*Below are some of the logs*

14:47:52.701 [Restlet-1879974483] WARN  o.a.c.processor.DeadLetterChannel - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-P2DBOO5-1580115331236-0-19 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-P2DBOO5-1580115331236-0-20). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:9902/CreateOppIDFolder with statusCode: 500 /n responseBody:org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.

14:48:15.044 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #15 - ErrorHandlerRedeliveryTask] WARN  o.a.c.processor.DeadLetterChannel - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-P2DBOO5-1580115331236-0-19 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-P2DBOO5-1580115331236-0-20). On delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:9902/CreateOppIDFolder with statusCode: 500 /n responseBody:org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.

14:48:37.252 [Camel (MyCamel) thread #17 - ErrorHandlerRedeliveryTask] WARN  o.a.c.processor.DeadLetterChannel - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-P2DBOO5-1580115331236-0-19 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-P2DBOO5-1580115331236-0-20). On delivery attempt: 2 caught: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:9902/CreateOppIDFolder with statusCode: 500 /n responseBody:org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.

**Any suggestions please?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is taking 24 seconds to **(begin the) retry**?

Couldn't it take around 24 seconds **until the retry fails** (end of retry)?

All three log statements are reporting an error 500 from the target endpoint. Is it possible that the retry starts after 2 seconds, makes the HTTP call, but it takes another 20 seconds until the endpoint answers with an error 500?

```
00:00 error occurs
00:02 Camel triggers retry after 2 seconds
00:02 HTTP call to http://localhost:9902...
00:xx Waiting for reponse from http://localhost:9902
00:2x Log output after 20-something seconds that retry is failed
```

Comment: Yeah it is taking around 24 seconds to begin a next retry if I provide 2 seconds as redelivery delay.
Not sure how it is taking 24 seconds if a retry fails.
I'm not sure of that, thinking camel takes 22 seconds by default, if we provide redelivery delay as 0 seconds and if we provide the delay as 2 seconds it adds to that default delay and retry the next redelivery.

Comment: I updated my answer, because I think you didn't get my point. What I try to say is that Camel triggers the retry correct after 2 seconds, but your log output is the final result of the retry, not the starting point.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. How can I get the next redelivery timestamp, is there any property in camel for that?

Comment: Not that I know, but you can change the HTTP endpoint to something that does not exist. This should give a very fast response. If the retry logs then show up much faster (after about 2 seconds), my guess is correct.